# how to read only last 24 hours from a multi dated log file and to grep specific pattern in python

Tags: python, python-regex

I am reading a file from a path `"F:\\RBS\\python\\Nobackupsimage.20230123"`

Nobackupsimage has log file on a different days like below. I want to open the file which was created in last 24 hours and look for a specific pattern as said in the below code:

```
Nobackupsimage.20230123
Nobackupsimage.20230122
Nobackupsimage.20230120
Nobackupsimage.20230121
```

My script output:

```
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of chsvm121626 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..chsvm121626.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126403 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126403.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126404 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126404.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126410 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126410.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126417 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126417.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126422 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126422.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126498 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126498.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126501 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126501.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126502 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126502.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126507 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126507.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126508 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126508.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126510 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126510.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126592 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126592.xp2) succeeded
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I look for a specific pattern and read a file that has changed in last 24 hour/8 hours ago only?

From my below output:

```
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126417 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126417.xp2)
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126410 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126410.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126417 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126417.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126422 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126422.xp2) succeeded
05/01/2023 05:38:46 Unix OS backup of delvm126498 (bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126498.xp2) succeeded
```

2. I want a regular expression to print the output like (server name and job name):

```
delvm126417 bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126417.xp2
delvm126410 bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126410.xp2
delvm126417 bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126417.xp2
delvm126422 bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126422.xp2
delvm126498 bkp.ind.inf.os.unv.ch4..delvm126498.xp2
```

code:

```py
import re

errors = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile("bkp.ind.inf.", re.IGNORECASE)

with open('F:\\RBS\\python\\Nobackupsimage.20230123.logtxt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if pattern.search(line) != None:
            errors.append((line.rstrip('\n')))
                   
    print("Below are the total Number of clients having issues, please check and fix:", (len(errors)))
    
    for err in errors:
        print(err)
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your code to limit what you're processing by date/time. Also, your regular expression is [potentially] wrong. Regardless, you don't need *re* for this

Comment: @pingu yes that is my question.How do I modify my code to process by date/time on a daily basis?

Comment: You will need to acquire a date/time from somewhere (user input perhaps) then, as you read through the file check to see if the dates in the file are within the range of interest. Also, you seem to be reporting "issues" even when the log shows "succeeded". Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log file appears to be formatted in pairs of significant data followed by a blank line. On that basis you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

FILENAME = 'F:\\RBS\\python\\Nobackupsimage.20230123.logtxt'

def pdate(s):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(s[:19], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return None

start = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1) # 24hrs prior to current date/time

with open(FILENAME) as log:
    while (line := next(log, None)) is not None:
        if (_date := pdate(line)) and _date >= start:
            server = line.split()[-1]
            if job := next(log, None):
                try:
                    detail, *_ = job.split()
                    print(server, detail[1:-1])
                except ValueError:
                    pass # unexpected format of line following a line with a relevant date
```